# Best way to get data from database android repeatedly

Tags: android

I have an app where I need to upload my current location every 2 sec and on the same time get that location on my second phone.

So what method should I use

I thought of uploading lanlng on mysql every 2 sec and on other phone call getting that row from mysql

So is this method ok or is there a better way to it.

Android app development

Answer (score 0):

Send LatLng to server and use GCM to deliver the LatLng to second phone when there is something new.

Comment: So in sending I every 2 second call http connection and upload lanlng into table at mysql

Comment: Yes. You can save it to mysql.